# Reloading animation script after div is replaced in AJAX load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div on my home page which uses a jQuery plugin called hoverwords to create roll-over animations for some links inside the div which looks like this:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">    
    <div class="animations">
            <a href="#" id="animatedText1">Text1</a>
            <a href="#" id="animatedText2">Text2</a>
            <a href="#" id="animatedText3">Text3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It loads the plugin just fine on first load using the following script:

```
$(function(){
     $(window).load(function(){
         $(".animations a").hoverwords();
     });    
});
```

I am then using AJAX to asynchronously load in the content from my other pages if JavaScript is enabled. Some of the other pages use the same hoverwords plugin and I am having a difficult time re-loading the script as it is not called as an event which I could potentially bind using .on() or .live(). Here's how I'm loading the new content using jQuery animation to hide the page then show the new page once loaded through AJAX:

```
$(function() {

$(".button").click(function() {

    var anchor = $("#contentWrapper");

    var pageHeight = $("#contentWrapper").height();

    var pageName = 'null';

    var extension = '.htm';

    if ($(this).attr('id')==='home') {
        pageName = 'index';
        extension = '.html';
    } else {
        pageName = $(this).attr('id');
    }

        $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : pageName + extension,

        success : function() {
            var $newContent = $('<div id="contentWrapper" />').load(pageName + extension + ' #contentWrapper > *');
            $("#contentWrapper").replaceWith($newContent);

        };
    });

});
});
```

I'm new to jQuery and may be doing this entirely the wrong way, but I'm completely stumped at this point as to how to get the same script re-applied to the newly loaded AJAX div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery load has a callback parameter that you can use to rebind your hoverwords functionality to the newly-added DOM elements. You'll want to use the callback handler so that you don't try to add the hoverwords to the DOM before your new content has been loaded:

```
 var $newContent = 
     $('<div id="contentWrapper" />')
         .load(pageName + extension + ' #contentWrapper > *', function() {

          // bind the hoverwords on the new content inserted in the DIV
          $("#contentWrapper").find(".animations a").hoverwords();

      });
```

Also, I'm not 100% sure that load returns anything to $newContent. This should be processed by the actual callback handler and added to the DIV#contentWrapper once the content is downloaded.  There are more examples of [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) in action on the jQuery site.

Comment: This ran hoverwords successfully as it is cutting up the href text and wrapping it in span tags like it does on first launch. Only problem now is that it's setting the spans created by the hoverword method to have a style of opacity 0 and width 0 although that violates the css rules I have for them...very strange.

Comment: If the hoverwords plugin is applying conflicting styles to your spans, you can either set more specific CSS rules to possibly override hoverwrapper's rules, or if that doesn't work, use !important to specify that your rules are of higher priority.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @jmort253! I updated the question if you wanted to take a look at it. It's a little more complicated then just over-riding the CSS generated by the hoverword() plugin.

Comment: Is that your code or code that's in the hoverwords library? If it's your code, then I think you might have all the ingredients for a new question :) Consider removing that update and posting your CSS problem as a new question. Not only will it eliminate clutter and distraction, but also it will make it easier to focus on this new problem. You're new, so I'll explain: Each question on SO is designed to be a resource for those who encounter a similar problem, so the more concise a question is, the more likely it will relate to others, and the more useful it will be. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've understood the question wrong, but you probably want to use live instead of load.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

edit:
Sorry, my bad. I would try just running

```
$("#contentWrapper").hoverwords()  // or $("#contentWrapper a").hoverwords()
```

again after you've replaced the content, but I'm going to stop guessing now. 
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Trying `var $newContent = $('<div id="contentWrapper" />').live(pageName + extension + ' #contentWrapper > *');` Just loads up an empty div with id="contentWrapper". I need to load the new div in from another page, but then re-apply the hoverwords() method to the new div.